# Getting specific data from xml -> php?

Tags: php, xml

I want to get to foreach loops from the following xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<data>
  <players>
    <player id="1">4</player>
    <player id="2">3</player>
  </players>
  <chats>
    <chat playerid="2">Some chat here...</chat>
    <chat playerid="1">skfgjh kjgh fdskgjhdf kgjhdf gkjd gkjdfhg dkfjhg</chat>
  </chats>
</data>
```

I want one foreach with the players and one with the chats, but can't seem to figure this out... I also wants the attributes out and don't know how?

Here is what i have tried:

```
$userXML = simplexml_load_file('xml_chats/0^0.xml') or die ("error");  

foreach($userXML->chats as $nchats){ 
    echo $nchats->chat.'<br>';     
}
```

What am I doing wrong and how can i achive this?

Thanks in advance :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the [xpath](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.xpath.php) method to select the nodes of your interest:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($xml);
$chats = $xml->xpath('/data/chats/chat');    
$players = $xml->xpath('/data/players/player');
```

Or you can use the magic mapping of simplexml to nodes like this:

```
foreach ($xml->players->player as $player) { ... }
foreach ($xml->chats->chat as $chat) { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
$xml=simplexml_load_file(filename);



foreach($xml->chats as $nchats){ 
    foreach($nchats as $chat)
    {
    echo $nchats->chat.'<br>';     
    foreach($chat->attributes() as $key=>$attrib)
    {
     echo $key."=>".$attrib.'<br>';
    }
    }
}
```